# How to search result must not sum of two values?

Tags: elasticsearch

How to write a correct query in elasticsearch for:

> phoneNumber != phoneCode + phone

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the fields are of type `text` and also have their sibling equivalent `keyword` type, I've shared a sample mapping, sample documents confirming to that mapping & the required query below:

### Mapping

```
PUT phone
{  
   "mappings":{  
      "mydocs":{  
         "properties":{  
            "phone":{  
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{  
                  "keyword":{  
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "phoneCode":{  
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{  
                  "keyword":{  
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "phoneNumber":{  
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{  
                  "keyword":{  
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

### Sample Documents

```
POST phone/mydocs/1
{
  "phoneNumber": "9654231010",
  "phoneCode": "0044",
  "phone": "9654231010"
}

POST phone/mydocs/2
{
  "phoneNumber": "00449654231010",
  "phoneCode": "0044",
  "phone": "9654231010"
}
```

### Query:

```
POST phone/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "script":{  
                  "script":"""
                  String phoneNumber = doc['phoneNumber.keyword'].value;
                  String phoneCode = doc['phoneCode.keyword'].value;
                  String phone = doc['phone.keyword'].value;

                  if(phoneNumber!=null && phoneCode!=null && phone!=null){
                    return phoneNumber != phoneCode + phone;
                  }
                  """
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I've implemented the condition you want using [Script Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) inside [Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/query-dsl-bool-query.html). Running the above query, should only fetch document having `id:1`

Now I've also assumed that `phoneNumber` and `phoneCode` either do not have hypen `-` in theirs values or its being used as a separator between them as shown in below example

```
phoneNumber: 0044-965-423-1010
phoneCode: 0044
phone: 965-423-1010
```

If that is how your values are you may want to use `contains()` method in your script as below:

```
POST phone/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "script":{  
                  "script":"""
                  String phoneNumber = doc['phoneNumber.keyword'].value;
                  String phoneCode = doc['phoneCode.keyword'].value;
                  String phone = doc['phone.keyword'].value;

                  if(phoneNumber!=null && phoneCode!=null && phone!=null){
                    return !(phoneNumber.contains(phoneCode) && phoneNumber.contains(phone));
                  }
                  """
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did the above answer help? Let me know if there is anything else you'd need. Happy to help!

Comment: Strange but query returns me results which equal to the number of documents in my index and it returns results without fields in the query "phonenumber,phonecode,phone". I made my query like:
GET http://myhost:9200/myindex/_search/

Comment: @AleksandrNidzelskiy Apologies for the delay. I've modified the both queries now. Do look at the logic where I've mentioned to take into consideration only documents having all three values available with the condition you are looking for.  Basically I've added some null checks. The query works correctly on the mapping I've created. Please test and let me know how it goes.